# Where can I find a mapping between Ubuntu release and exact Ubuntu kernel version(not just mainline) with which it was released?

Tags: kernel, updates

I need to download the source codes of Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and its updates from the repository http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git/

For that, I really need to know the exact kernel version of Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS to choose the source from tags. Also I need, the list of updates' source codes to that particular LTS.

Any idea about where can I get these details?

I would like to have version in following format to choose the exact source tag.

```
[base kernel version]-[ABI number].[upload number]
```

Comment: I think it is not a duplicate of that question as those answers have only mapping to mainline kernel versions. I would like to have version in following format to choose the exact source tag.                                  <base kernel version>-<ABI number>.<upload number>

Comment: @Vicky: Then say so in the question. Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information.It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04.4 is obsolete. It used kernel 3.11 that is the kernel from 13.10 saucy release. It is not supported.

The supported version is 12.04.5 that has 3.13 kernel from

```
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git
```